Right memory_order to react on atomic increment changes in other thread?
Consider such code:
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

bool read_from_network() noexcept;
void write_to_network() noexcept;

int main() {
  std::atomic<size_t> work_counter;

  std::thread t1([&work_counter] {
    while (true) {
      if (read_from_network())
        work_counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
    }
  });

  std::thread t2([&work_counter] {
    const auto prev_val = work_counter.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    write_to_network();
    const auto new_val = work_counter.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (new_val != prev_val) {
      // get reply **after** write_to_network
    }
  });

  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}

t2 initiate some operation, and want to check if it happens via comparing
atomic counter value.
Do I choose right std::memory_order ?
Can I use memory_order_relaxed and still get correctly working program,
or should I use memory_order_seq_cst, because of my program is incorrect ?
And I should mention, that if "network event" happens after const auto prev_val = work_counter.load(std::memory_order_acquire);, but before  start_operation_that_emit_network_event() do real job, it is unimportant, and I can leave with this.

All operations default to memory_order_seq_cst. Is there a particular reason to use something else?

We wouldn't know, we can't tell what you're doing after new_val != prev_val and work_counter does absolutely nothing. The code also doesn't compile, please provide a [mre].

If there's a system call in write_to_network(), in practice a compiler won't be able to reorder it with the second load.  If not, this is basically the same problem as the read side of a seqlock: check if a counter changed before / after something else.  In that case you want std::atomic_thread_fence(acquire) after write_to_network(), before the second read, to prevent the load from reordering with stuff before it.  (And the second load itself might as well be relaxed, unless you do more stuff.)
